# Python 3.x Hexdump

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, serialization, compression

I posted a small hexdump generator function from a program I've been writing not long ago and applied what a reviewer suggested since then. The goal was to lazily hexdump bytes objects (byte strings, binary files without committing to I/O code).

Here is the relevant code (minus docstrings/tests/script), with some description below:

```
import re
from itertools import islice


class HexdumpGenerator:
    def __init__(self, iterable, base_addr=0, start=0, stop=None, step=16, sep='\b'):
        self.iterable = islice(iterable, start, stop)
        self.base_addr = base_addr
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop
        self.step = step
        self.col0 = '08X'
        self.col1 = '02X'
        self.fmt = '{}   {}  {}'
        self.placeholder = ['  ']
        self._sep = sep[0]
        self._mod = (base_addr + start) % self.step
        self._next = start + self.step - self._mod

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            row = bytearray(islice(self.iterable, self._next - self.start))
            if not row:
                break
            col0 = format(self.base_addr + self.start - self._mod, self.col0)
            col1 = self._mod * self.placeholder
            col2 = self._mod * ' '
            for byte in row:
                ch = chr(byte)
                col1 += [format(byte, self.col1)]
                col2 += ch if ch.isprintable() else '.'
            self._mod = self.step - len(col1)
            col1 += self._mod * self.placeholder
            col2 += self._mod * ' '
            col1.insert(self.step // 2, self._sep)
            yield self.fmt.format(col0, ' '.join(col1), col2)
            self.start = self._next
            self._next += self.step


class CompressHexdumpGenerator(HexdumpGenerator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompressHexdumpGenerator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.row = ''
        self.delimiter = ' '
        self.duplicates = 0

    def _compress(self):
        index = self.row.index(self.delimiter)
        col0 = int(self.row[:index], 16)
        col0 += self.duplicates * self.step
        return format(col0, self.col0) + self.row[index:]

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in super().__iter__():
            if self.row.split()[1:] == i.split()[1:]:
                if not self.duplicates:
                    yield '*'
                self.duplicates += 1
            else:
                yield i
                self.row = i
                self.duplicates = 0
        if self.duplicates:
            yield self._compress()


class FromHexdumpGenerator(CompressHexdumpGenerator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FromHexdumpGenerator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base = 16
        self.len = '3'

    def get_repr(self, _row):
        row = bytearray()
        for i in _row[2:self.step * 2 + 1]:
            if i.isalnum():
                row.append(int(i, self.base))
            elif re.match('(\s{' + self.len + ',})', i):
                break
        return row

    def decompress_gen(self, row0, row1):
        i = int(row0[0].rstrip(self.delimiter), 16) + self.step
        j = int(row1[0].rstrip(self.delimiter), 16)
        while not i >= j:
            row = format(i, self.col0) + self.delimiter
            row = [row.rstrip(' ')] + row0[1:]
            yield self.get_repr(row)
            i += self.step

    def __iter__(self):
        i = j = ''
        while True:
            row = j if j else next(self.iterable, None)
            if row is None:
                break
            elif row == '*' or row == '*\n':
                j = next(self.iterable)
                yield from self.decompress_gen(i, j.split())
            else:
                index = row.find(self._sep)
                i = row[:index] + row[index + 1:]
                i = re.split('(\s+)', i)
                j = ''
                yield self.get_repr(i)
```

Utility functions:

```
from itertools import chain


def read_binary_gen(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        yield from chain.from_iterable(f)


def write(file, gen):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for i in gen:
            f.write(i + '\n')


def read_gen(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        yield from f


def write_binary(file, gen):
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        for i in gen:
            f.write(i)
```

`read_binary_gen()` is meant to be passed to the first two generator classes, while `read_gen` to the latter, thus not reading a file into memory.

I've tested the code with different formats (`03o`, `03d`): if specifying `03d`, then the `placeholder` attribute must be assigned a list with a single string composed of 3 spaces. Using `FromHexdumpGenerator` to undo the hexdump would then require that `base` be assigned the integer 10, and `len` the number `'4'` (3 + 1). The `col0` attribute must remain hex (as it is an address).

If `fmt`'s first column ends with a colon (as I've seen other programs use), the `delimiter` must be set to that value.

I struggled with different encodings before figuring out this was a case for `bytearray`, so if a bytes object can be dumped, it can be undumped.

**EDIT**

@Peilonrayz I attempted to fix the issues you pointed out and came up with the following (this is the whole module, with some additional functionality I'd been working on):

```
from itertools import islice, takewhile, tee, chain
from re import match, split
from copy import copy
from colorama import init, Style

tee = tee
init()

COL0 = '08X'
COL1 = '02X'
PAD = '  '
FMT = '{}   {}  {}'
DLM = ' '
BASE = 16


def change_format(col0, col1, fmt=''):
    global COL0, COL1, PAD, FMT, DLM, BASE
    COL0 = col0
    COL1 = col1
    PAD = ' ' * int(col1[:-1])
    if fmt:
        FMT = fmt
        DLM = fmt[fmt.index('}') + 1]
    BASE = {'b': 2, 'o': 8, 'd': 10, 'x': 16, 'X': 16}[col1[-1]]


def fix(it, offset, start, stop, step):
    n = (offset + start) % step
    return islice(it, start, stop), n, start + step - n


def mk_row(it, nxt, start):
    return bytearray(islice(it, nxt - start))


def to_hex(i):
    return format(i, COL1)


def to_chr(i):
    i = chr(i)
    return i if i.isprintable() else '.'


def pad_gen(fn, pad, it, n, step):
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        yield pad
    for i in it:
        yield fn(i)
        count += 1
    while count < step - n:
        yield pad
        count += 1


def hexdump_gen(it, offset=0, start=0, stop=None, step=16, sep='\b'):
    it, n, nxt = fix(it, offset, start, stop, step)
    while True:
        row = mk_row(it, nxt, start)
        if not row:
            break
        args = row, n, step
        col0 = format(offset + start - n, COL0)
        col1 = list(pad_gen(to_hex, PAD, *args))
        col2 = ''.join(pad_gen(to_chr, ' ', *args))
        col1.insert(step // 2, sep)
        yield FMT.format(col0, ' '.join(col1), col2)
        start = nxt
        nxt += step
        n = 0


def compress_hexdump_gen(*args, **kwargs):
    row = ''
    duplicates = 0
    for i in hexdump_gen(*args, **kwargs):
        if row.split()[1:] == i.split()[1:]:
            if not duplicates:
                yield '*'
            duplicates += 1
        else:
            yield i
            row = i
            duplicates = 0
    if duplicates > 1:
        index = row.index(DLM)
        col0 = int(row[:index], 16)
        col0 += duplicates * kwargs.get('step', 16)
        yield format(col0, COL0) + row[index:]


def predicate(i):
    return not match('(\s{3,})', i)


def highlight(row, sep, ba):
    for n, i in enumerate(takewhile(predicate, copy(row))):
        if ' ' not in i and i != sep:
            j = int(i, BASE)
            if j in ba or (not ba and chr(j).isprintable()):
                row[n] = Style.BRIGHT + i + Style.RESET_ALL


def highlight_hexdump_gen(it, step=16, sep='\b', ba=b''):
    ba = bytearray(ba)
    index = step * 2 + (1 if not sep else 3)
    for i in it:
        row0 = split('(\s+)', i)
        row1 = row0[2:index]
        highlight(row1, sep, ba)
        yield ''.join(row0[:2] + row1 + row0[index:])


def to_bytes(row, step):
    ba = bytearray()
    for i in takewhile(predicate, row[2:step * 2 + 1]):
        i = i.replace(Style.BRIGHT, '').replace(Style.RESET_ALL, '')
        if i.isalnum():
            ba.append(int(i, BASE))
    return ba


def decompress_gen(row0, row1, step):
    i = int(row0[0].rstrip(DLM), 16) + step
    j = int(row1[0].rstrip(DLM), 16)
    while not i >= j:
        row = [(format(i, COL0) + DLM).rstrip(' ')] + row0[1:]
        yield to_bytes(row, step)
        i += step


def from_hexdump_gen(it, step=16, sep='\b'):
    i = j = ''
    while True:
        row = j if j else next(it, None)
        if row is None:
            break
        elif row == '*' or row == '*\n':
            j = next(it, ''.join(i))
            yield from decompress_gen(i, j.split(), step)
        else:
            index = row.find(sep)
            i = row[:index] + row[index + 1:]
            i = split('(\s+)', i)
            j = ''
            yield to_bytes(i, step)


def test(it0, it1, offset=0, start=0, stop=None, step=16, sep='\b'):
    it1, _, nxt = fix(it1, offset, start, stop, step)
    for i in from_hexdump_gen(it0, step=step, sep=sep):
        if mk_row(it1, nxt, start) != i:
            break
        start = nxt
        nxt += step
    else:
        return True


def read_binary_gen(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        yield from chain.from_iterable(f)


def write(file, gen):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for i in gen:
            f.write(i + '\n')


def read_gen(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        yield from f


def write_binary(file, gen):
    with open(file, 'wb') as f:
        for i in gen:
            f.write(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

- Don't use a class when you don't need to. A generator is good enough for this, and makes the code much clearer.
- Make functions/classes responsible for one thing. `HexdumpGenerator` changes the iterable and formats.
- Use better variable names, `self._mod` is beyond cryptic. As in this took me a long while to understand, as it's not really modulo, and I can't think of anything else that shortens to mod. How about `padding`.
- Rather than having to care about `base_addr` and `start` in your `__iter__`, you could just change the beginning of the iterable to `None`, and make it print empty information on `None`.
- Rather than adding variables to your class try to keep them only in function scope. This makes them *much* easier to work with, and reason with. Plus the only variables you use in child classes are `step`, `col0`, `delimiter`, `iterable` and `_sep`. Which don't change after `__iter__`.
- I don't think `CompressHexdumpGenerator` works correctly:

  First, I checked what it outputted:

  ```
  >>> print('\n'.join(list(CompressHexdumpGenerator(map(ord, '123456781234567812345678'), step=8))))
  self._compress
  00000000   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38  12345678
  *
  00000010   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38  12345678
  >>> print('\n'.join(list(CompressHexdumpGenerator(map(ord, '123456781234567812345679'), step=8))))
  00000000   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38  12345678
  *
  00000010   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 39  12345679
  >>> print('\n'.join(list(CompressHexdumpGenerator(map(ord, '123456781234567912345679'), step=8))))
  00000000   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38  12345678
  00000008   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 39  12345679
  *
  00000010   31 32 33 34  35 36 37 39  12345679
  ```

  The first and second kind of make sense. I don't really get why you'd care about the *very last*, but none of the ones in-between. Maybe so you have the last index, IDK. But the last example from above makes no sense, why should it output `*`? It's just a waist of a line and makes me go 'huh, nothing's there'.
- If I'm reading things correctly, you don't need `_compress` if you move `self.row = i` out of the `if else` statement, since all you change is the index to that of the last.

And so ignoring the possible `CompressHexdumpGenerator` bug, I'd change your code to heavily use `itertools`, rather than use some odd mutation stuff:

```
import itertools

def byte_gen(iterable, chunk=1024):
    while True:
        ret = bytearray(islice(iterable, chunk))
        if not ret:
            break
        yield from ret


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def hex_iter_changer(iterable, base_addr=0, start=0, stop=None, chunk=1024):
    sliced = itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop)
    byte_slice = byte_gen(sliced)
    empty_prefix = itertools.repeat(None, base_addr + start)
    return itertools.chain(empty_prefix, byte_slice)


def _hexdump_generator(iterable, base_addr=0, start=0, stop=None, width=16, sep='\b'):
    iterable = hex_iter_changer(iterable, base_addr, start, stop)
    groups = grouper(iterable, width)
    for index, group in zip(itertools.count(0, width), groups):
        group = list(group)
        yield (
            index,
            [
                None if byte is None else format(byte, '02X')
                for byte in group
            ],
            [
                None if byte is None else chr(byte)
                for byte in group
            ]
        )


def hexdump_generator(iterable, base_addr=0, start=0, stop=None, width=16, sep='\b'):
    middle = width // 2
    for index, hex_values, values in _hexdump_generator(iterable, base_addr, start, stop, width, sep):
        hex_values = ['  ' if byte is None else byte for byte in hex_values]
        hex_values.insert(middle, sep)
        values = [' ' if char is None else char for char in values]
        yield '{:08X}   {}  {}'.format(index, ' '.join(hex_values), ''.join(values))


def compress_hexdump_generator(iterable, base_addr=0, start=0, stop=None, width=16, sep='\b'):
    prev = ''
    duplicates = 0
    for row in hexdump_generator(iterable, base_addr, start, stop, width, sep):
        if prev.split()[1:] == row.split()[1:]:
            if not duplicates:
                yield '*'
            duplicates += 1
        else:
            yield row
            duplicates = 0
        prev = row
    if duplicates:
        yield prev
```

Comment: You are right, and your end result looks pretty good. I should've looked into `_compress` more recently. I wanted the last row for undoing. Without it, I could not restore a binary file. Thanks for pointing it out.